# Update to latest version from command line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there an SVN command-line utility that allows you to update a given directory / repository to the latest version?

I would like to be able to remotely update our development server without having to go into remote desktop etc., as there are often times where all the RD terminals are in use, if it was command line I could do it via SSH, for example.

Cheers, Ed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [command-line client](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for Subversion. You can see the usage options it offers if you type `svn help`. The one for updating would be simply `svn up`.

Answer (score 10):

Simply type `svn update [name-of-directory]`, or `cd` to that directory and type `svn update` there.

Comment: this is the correct one command, to checkout the latest revision using tortoise *svn update*

Answer (score 8):

It's called "svn.exe":

```
svn up .
```

will update the current folder.

You can download a pre-built Windows command line client without registration from [slik](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/) or one with registration from [collabnet](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).

Answer (score 6):

```
svn update/up
```

svn update or svn up. This command syncs your local sand box with the server. If you have made local changes, it will try and merge any changes on the server with your changes on your machine.

You can view some [basic commands here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html#ch03-update)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [collabnet subversion](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/).

Comment: We use tortoise on all our projects, so switching svn server etc. is not really an option.

Comment: We use tortoise, too. It doesn't conflict with other command line tools like the one of collabnet.

Comment: You don't need to change the server, you only need a command-line client.

Comment: oh, I'll check it out then, sorry, I'm not exactly an svn power-user :)

Comment: svn was developed as a command-line tool; the GUI clients came later.

Comment: Note that collabnet requires registration. You can get the same from slik without that hassle. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532476/1532506#1532506)

Comment: The question clearly requested command-line compatible solution due to remote execution